# Why can't i fetch data from a passed value?

Tags: reactjs, fetch, state

I tried to fetch the value which is my product information by passing the value from my context.js to my ProductsList.js. However, when i console.log the value in the ProductsList.js my console doesn't  fetch the data...I don't know what is wrong, can anybody help me? Thank you so much!

This is my context.js:

```
import React from "react";
import {
    storeProducts,
    detailProduct
} from "./data";

const ProductContext = React.createContext();

//provider
//consumer

class ProductProvider extends React.Component {
    state = {
        products: storeProducts,
        detailProduct: detailProduct
    };
    handleDetail = () => {
        console.log("hello products");
    };
    addToCart = () => {
        console.log("hello details");
    };
    render() {
        return ( <
            ProductContext.Provider value = {
                {
                    ...this.state,
                        handleDetail: this.handleDetail,
                        addToCart: this.addToCart
                }
            } >
            <
            /ProductContext.Provider>
        );
    }
}

const ProductConsumer = ProductContext.Consumer;

export {
    ProductProvider,
    ProductConsumer
};
```

This is my ProductsList.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Product from "./Product";
import Title from "./Title.js";
import { storeProducts } from "../data";

import { ProductConsumer } from "../context";
export default class ProductsList extends Component {
  state = {
    products: storeProducts,
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className="py-5">
          <div className="container">
            <Title name="our" title="products" />
            <div className="row">
              <ProductConsumer>
                {" "}
                {(value) => {
                  console.log(value);
                }}{" "}
              </ProductConsumer>{" "}
            </div>{" "}
          </div>{" "}
        </div>{" "}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

This is my data.js:

```
/* 
https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/1243689/call_phone_icon
Creative Commons (Attribution 3.0 Unported);
https://www.iconfinder.com/Makoto_msk */

export const storeProducts = [{
    id: 1,
    title: "Google Pixel - Black",
    img: "img/product-1.png",
    price: 10,
    company: "GOOGLE",
    info: "Lorem ipsum dolor amet offal butcher quinoa sustainable gastropub, echo park actually green juice sriracha paleo. Brooklyn sriracha semiotics, DIY coloring book mixtape craft beer sartorial hella blue bottle. Tote bag wolf authentic try-hard put a bird on it mumblecore. Unicorn lumbersexual master cleanse blog hella VHS, vaporware sartorial church-key cardigan single-origin coffee lo-fi organic asymmetrical. Taxidermy semiotics celiac stumptown scenester normcore, ethical helvetica photo booth gentrify.",
    inCart: false,
    count: 0,
    total: 0
}, {
    id: 2,
    title: "Samsung S7",
    img: "img/product-2.png",
    price: 16,
    company: "SAMSUNG",
    info: "Lorem ipsum dolor amet offal butcher quinoa sustainable gastropub, echo park actually green juice sriracha paleo. Brooklyn sriracha semiotics, DIY coloring book mixtape craft beer sartorial hella blue bottle. Tote bag wolf authentic try-hard put a bird on it mumblecore. Unicorn lumbersexual master cleanse blog hella VHS, vaporware sartorial church-key cardigan single-origin coffee lo-fi organic asymmetrical. Taxidermy semiotics celiac stumptown scenester normcore, ethical helvetica photo booth gentrify.",
    inCart: false,
    count: 0,
    total: 0
}, {
    id: 3,
    title: "HTC 10 - Black",
    img: "img/product-3.png",
    price: 8,
    company: "htc",
    info: "Lorem ipsum dolor amet offal butcher quinoa sustainable gastropub, echo park actually green juice sriracha paleo. Brooklyn sriracha semiotics, DIY coloring book mixtape craft beer sartorial hella blue bottle. Tote bag wolf authentic try-hard put a bird on it mumblecore. Unicorn lumbersexual master cleanse blog hella VHS, vaporware sartorial church-key cardigan single-origin coffee lo-fi organic asymmetrical. Taxidermy semiotics celiac stumptown scenester normcore, ethical helvetica photo booth gentrify.",
    inCart: false,
    count: 0,
    total: 0
}, {
    id: 4,
    title: "HTC 10 - White",
    img: "img/product-4.png",
    price: 18,
    company: "htc",
    info: "Lorem ipsum dolor amet offal butcher quinoa sustainable gastropub, echo park actually green juice sriracha paleo. Brooklyn sriracha semiotics, DIY coloring book mixtape craft beer sartorial hella blue bottle. Tote bag wolf authentic try-hard put a bird on it mumblecore. Unicorn lumbersexual master cleanse blog hella VHS, vaporware sartorial church-key cardigan single-origin coffee lo-fi organic asymmetrical. Taxidermy semiotics celiac stumptown scenester normcore, ethical helvetica photo booth gentrify.",
    inCart: false,
    count: 0,
    total: 0
}, {
    id: 5,
    title: "HTC Desire 626s",
    img: "img/product-5.png",
    price: 24,
    company: "htc",
    info: "Lorem ipsum dolor amet offal butcher quinoa sustainable gastropub, echo park actually green juice sriracha paleo. Brooklyn sriracha semiotics, DIY coloring book mixtape craft beer sartorial hella blue bottle. Tote bag wolf authentic try-hard put a bird on it mumblecore. Unicorn lumbersexual master cleanse blog hella VHS, vaporware sartorial church-key cardigan single-origin coffee lo-fi organic asymmetrical. Taxidermy semiotics celiac stumptown scenester normcore, ethical helvetica photo booth gentrify.",
    inCart: false,
    count: 0,
    total: 0
}, {
    id: 6,
    title: "Vintage Iphone",
    img: "img/product-6.png",
    price: 17,
    company: "apple",
    info: "Lorem ipsum dolor amet offal butcher quinoa sustainable gastropub, echo park actually green juice sriracha paleo. Brooklyn sriracha semiotics, DIY coloring book mixtape craft beer sartorial hella blue bottle. Tote bag wolf authentic try-hard put a bird on it mumblecore. Unicorn lumbersexual master cleanse blog hella VHS, vaporware sartorial church-key cardigan single-origin coffee lo-fi organic asymmetrical. Taxidermy semiotics celiac stumptown scenester normcore, ethical helvetica photo booth gentrify.",
    inCart: false,
    count: 0,
    total: 0
}, {
    id: 7,
    title: "Iphone 7",
    img: "img/product-7.png",
    price: 30,
    company: "apple",
    info: "Lorem ipsum dolor amet offal butcher quinoa sustainable gastropub, echo park actually green juice sriracha paleo. Brooklyn sriracha semiotics, DIY coloring book mixtape craft beer sartorial hella blue bottle. Tote bag wolf authentic try-hard put a bird on it mumblecore. Unicorn lumbersexual master cleanse blog hella VHS, vaporware sartorial church-key cardigan single-origin coffee lo-fi organic asymmetrical. Taxidermy semiotics celiac stumptown scenester normcore, ethical helvetica photo booth gentrify.",
    inCart: false,
    count: 0,
    total: 0
}, {
    id: 8,
    title: "Smashed Iphone",
    img: "img/product-8.png",
    price: 2,
    company: "apple",
    info: "Lorem ipsum dolor amet offal butcher quinoa sustainable gastropub, echo park actually green juice sriracha paleo. Brooklyn sriracha semiotics, DIY coloring book mixtape craft beer sartorial hella blue bottle. Tote bag wolf authentic try-hard put a bird on it mumblecore. Unicorn lumbersexual master cleanse blog hella VHS, vaporware sartorial church-key cardigan single-origin coffee lo-fi organic asymmetrical. Taxidermy semiotics celiac stumptown scenester normcore, ethical helvetica photo booth gentrify.",
    inCart: false,
    count: 0,
    total: 0
}];

export const detailProduct = {
    id: 1,
    title: "Google Pixel - Black",
    img: "img/product-1.png",
    price: 10,
    company: "google",
    info: "Lorem ipsum dolor amet offal butcher quinoa sustainable gastropub, echo park actually green juice sriracha paleo. Brooklyn sriracha semiotics, DIY coloring book mixtape craft beer sartorial hella blue bottle. Tote bag wolf authentic try-hard put a bird on it mumblecore. Unicorn lumbersexual master cleanse blog hella VHS, vaporware sartorial church-key cardigan single-origin coffee lo-fi organic asymmetrical. Taxidermy semiotics celiac stumptown scenester normcore, ethical helvetica photo booth gentrify.",
    inCart: false,
    count: 0,
    total: 0
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be missing *actually* providing the context value to your app. The provider needs to wrap the `children` prop in order to provide anything to them.

```
class ProductProvider extends React.Component {
  state = {
    products: storeProducts,
    detailProduct: detailProduct
  };

  handleDetail = () => {
    console.log("hello products");
  };

  addToCart = () => {
    console.log("hello details");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <ProductContext.Provider
        value = {{
          ...this.state,
          handleDetail: this.handleDetail,
          addToCart: this.addToCart
        }}
      >
        {this.props.children} // <-- render children sub-tree
      </ProductContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

#### Update

Adding running codesandbox

[image: Edit why-cant-i-fetch-data-from-a-passed-value]

Comment: Yah i did but then it has the error: "render is not a method" again

Comment: @sugasunshie Your code with my fix appears to render fine. Check the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/why-cant-i-fetch-data-from-a-passed-value-687e5) I added in my answer. You might have some other issue in your code beyond what you've included in your question.

Comment: Hello sir, i very appreciate your effort to help me. I have added the map function to map through every Product in the ProductList but it doesn't render the Product again. It'd be kind of you to help me one more time! Thank you so much This is the link to my codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/why-cant-i-fetch-data-from-a-passed-value-forked-30bgi?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @sugasunshie You're not retuning anything from the map callback in `ProductsList`. In other words, you need a `return <Product key={product.id} product={product} />;` in the mapping callback function. https://codesandbox.io/s/why-cant-i-fetch-data-from-a-passed-value-forked-eg6ss?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Hello sir, i'm supposed to display the icon when the inCart value is false, but now my shopping cart icon is not showing up, it'd be kind of you if you can help me again. Btw, sorry if my work has bothered you. This is my codesandbox link:https://codesandbox.io/s/why-cant-i-fetch-data-from-a-passed-value-forked-30bgi

Comment: @sugasunshie If you are referring to the `<i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i>` icon then I see it rendered on the page. ***However***... your CSS when hovering the cart item it scales the image and covers the cart icon/button.

Answer (score 0):

Access your data by context.products
Here is an example

```
<ProductContext.Provider value={{ products: storeProducts }}>
   {this.props.children}
</ProductContext.Provider>
```

In your product list

```
<ProductConsumer>
    {(context) => (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className="py-5">
          <div className="container">
            {context.products.map((element) => (
              <p>{element.title}</p>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    )}
</ProductConsumer>
```